# You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period

Tags: discussion

I opened a new account and attempted to post a question and this was the error that I got:

```
You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period.
```

Why should it happen with new account? What is the reason?

Answer (score 6):

If someone could simply create a new account to get around such rate limiting there wouldn't really be much of a point in having it in the first place, so accounts that are not established users share their rate limiting with other users on the same connection.